# I watched a cartoon in the 80s or early 90s where the robot has a football helmet, and pumps the face mask before attacking

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I thought it was *Mighty Orbots*, but finally watched it. Nope. Found Gordian Warriors, but that wasn't it. The sequence of pumping the face mask was a recurring bit of the pre-fight montage. Any ideas of title?

Comment: What do you mean by pumping the face mask?  Hitting it or something else?  I assume you mean American football?

Comment: Botsmaster had a bunch of sports-themed robots, as well as a "power-up" 3d segment. I don't specifically recall a football robot, but here's a screenshot of the main gang in case it jogs your memory: https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fkcyclzrq3d851.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This could be [*"UFO Warrior Dai Apolon"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_Warrior_Dai_Apolon) (also known as *UFO Diapolon* in some dubbed versions).

It's a mecha anime originally aired in Japan in 1976; you could have seen a dubbed version in later years, or the movie, created by heavily editing and adapting the first episodes, that was released in 1986 according to the Wikipedia article linked above.

The main characters are three kids playing in the American football team of their orphanage; the three robots they control can join to create the larger and more powerful Daiapolon, which (for reasons unknown) appears to be football-themed.

[image: Diapolon]